# PHP Replace all characters other than [a-zA-Z0-9\-]

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace all characters in a string other than `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` with a space.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/894792) and no matter how many times I tweak the REGEX, I can't get it to "don't match [a-zA-Z0-9-], only match and replace other characters".

At the moment, I have the following:

```
$original_name = trim(' How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?  ');

$replace_strange_characters = preg_replace("/^((?!([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*))$/", " ", $original_name);

// Returns: How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?
echo $replace_strange_characters;
```

I wish for it to replace all of the strange characters with a space ' ', thus returning:

```
How to get file creation   modification date times in Python?
```

I'm really struggling with these "don't match" scenarios.

Here's my code so far: http://tehplayground.com/#2NFzGbG7B

Comment: I wish to retain dashes, using `\w` as suggested in the answers for that question would not have the desired effect. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (You mentioned you want to keep dash)

```
$original_name = trim(' How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?  ');
$replace_strange_characters = preg_replace('/[^\da-z-]/i', ' ', $original_name);
echo $replace_strange_characters;
```

<del>[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2pEYKD)</del>

Comment: I think that link rot has set in...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this regex do it?

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]
```

Oh, and why are you doing this btw?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but your example doesn't say "no not match" anything?

Comment: @Coulton Eh? It says matching anything but a-zA-Z0-9\- (with other words, not a-zA-Z0-9\-, but everything else).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$replace_strange_characters = preg_replace("([^a-zA-Z0-9\-\?])", " ", $original_name);
```

The previous answer strip out the `?`